# Asp.net Identity 2.0 - Unique PhoneNumber [How To Set]

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-identity

How To Get Unique PhoneNumber in Asp.Net Identity Like

```
RequireUniqueEmail=True;
```

in `App_Start/IdentityConfig.cs`